# Samsung logo loop in galaxy y

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-y

Whenever I start my phone, the **samsung logo animation goes in a loop forever**; unless i take off the battery. This started happening after I simultaneously clicked the power button, menu button and volume up button and going to android system recovery and doing wipe data/factory reset. After that it goes on in a loop.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: The wipe you've described should normally solve such a problem. Are you sure you didn't wipe anything else?

Comment: Then I wiped the cache too after it went in a loop

Comment: Cache shouldn't be a problem either -- that's included with a factory reset anyway. You didn't actually run some "format" menu items, and e.g. formatted/wiped "system" or the like?

Comment: Sorry it is cache partition. I had then wiped cache partition hoping that it would fix the loop.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact procedure to do the wipe. I clicked reboot after doing the wipe. Is that the cause of the problem?

Comment: No, that's all fine. As long as you didn't touch anything but the cache and data partition, this should not cause any problems. And a reboot is what one usually does after that (as one wants to get out of the recovery menu and back into the "main system"). So again, was that all you did -- or did you do anything else, except from "wipe data, wipe cache, factory-reset, reboot"?

Comment: No. I only did the last two options in the android recovery in samsung galaxy y.

Comment: That leaves me confused. Are you at least able to boot into safe mode (see the [safe-mode tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) for details)?

Comment: Are you running a custom recovery or just the one that came with the phone?

Comment: I simultaneously clicked the power button, menu button and volume up button and going to android system recovery and doing wipe data/factory reset and cache partition

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution that is specific to Samsung devices. This will only work if you have soft-bricked your device. It is pretty simple to build and can get you into download mode on most Samsung devices, just have your ROM ready to flash and you're good to go!

- http://www.xda-developers.com/android/need-a-samsung-usb-jig-build-your-own/

Here is the actual YouTube video that I used to make mine:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rdn5GoRjhn0

Answer (score 1):

Here are some quick tips :

(Here I'll use the terms like Download-Mode & Recovery-Mode, If you dont know what they are google it. ("BOOT to RECOVERY" & "BOOT to BOOTLOADER" means how to enter into Recovery-Mode & Download-Mode respectively.)

A Bricked Phone May Have One or More (Below Problems) :

1. Booting to the ROM(Android) not possible.
2. Booting to the Recovery-Mode not possible.
3. Black screen or Bootloop(Repeated Restarting of Phone at Boot Animation or Samsung Galaxy Y Logo).

Possible Solutions :
(Remember there'll be data loss using these solutions so always try to keep a backup)

1. If you can still enter into Recovery-Mode 
   (a). Try to clear Data & Cache then check.
   (b). Try Installing a Custom ROM using CWM(ClockWorkMod Recovery) & check.
   (For Custom ROM & CWM Visit [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1534510).)
2. If Recovery-Mode didn't helped Enter into Download-Mode & flash an odin supported stock rom(using ODIN 1.84 or 1.85) from [Doky73's Thread(Flashing Guide in 2nd post)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1465800).

*You can inform me, if anything left out.
 you must try going in download mode!